# oracle database connection in java program

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

[image]

```
 import java.sql.*;
 import java.io.*;

 public class OracleCon {


public static void main(String []args)throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException,IOException
{

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "123456789");
Statement st=con.createStatement();
String sql="insert into citylist values ('vijay','54222','110001')";
int r=st.executeUpdate(sql);

if(r>0)
{
    System.out.print("value inserted");
}
else
{
    System.out.print("value not inserted");
}
//ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

//while(rs.next())
//  System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+""+rs.getString(2)+""+rs.getString(3));
con.close();


  }
}
```

I have installed oracle 11g and jdk 1.8 at windows 7

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown source)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (Unknown source)

Comment: SO rule is put exception here, in form of text

Comment: Put the Oracle driver onto CLASSPATH...

Comment: FYI: the two images are the same

Answer (score 2):

When you run your program in Command Line, you must include the jar file path in front of classpath parameter like this:

```
java OracleCon -classpath c:\somepath\ojdbc6.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are missing the actual jdbc driver for your Java version.

[ojdbc6.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) should do the trick for versions 6, 7 and 8.

Also don't forget to add the driver file to your classpath.
If you are using Eclipse you can do that via right click on your project:

```
Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries
```